# Fetching Wordpress articles and put it in Flutter Story app

Tags: flutter

I built a story app UI in flutter and I want to fetch the articles from my wordpress website and view them in the app.

Is there any way to do it or any tutorial available?

Comment: You don't seem to have a concrete coding problem. Please check the question guidelines to improve the chances of getting some quality answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This [Cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook) contains recipes that demonstrate how to solve common problems while writing Flutter apps. Each recipe is self-contained and can be used as a reference to help you build up an application.